# Using custom computation expression operator inside match statement

Tags: f#, computation-expression

Right now I'm experimenting with F# computation expressions. General idea is to return control mechanism to drive actions executed after each step of recursive function call build from computation expression. Whole example can be seen [here](https://github.com/Horusiath/Akkling/blob/actor-expression-2.0/src/Akkling/ActorBuilder.fs).

Using following example:

```
let rec loop () =
    actor {
        let! msg = m.Receive ()
        match msg with
        | "stop" -> return 0        // expected result: Return (0)
        | "unhandled" -> unhandled  // expected result: Unhandled 
        | x -> 
            mailbox.Sender() <! x
            return! loop ()         // expected result: (Become(fun m -> loop ()))
    }
loop ()
```

Unfortunately this ends with compile time error on `unhandled`: *A custom operation may not be used in conjunction with 'use', 'try/with', 'try/finally', 'if/then/else' or 'match' operators within this computation expression*.

Is it possible in any way to use custom operators inside match statements?

Comment: what is `unhandled`?  And - assuming it`s of the right type - why don't you use `return` or `return!` as well?

Comment: `unhandled` is a custom operator. In general Return and ReturnFrom are able to return discriminated union of type `Return` or `Become` depending on, if expression is a value or recursive function call. This DU is later used to apply additional logic. What I wanted to do, was to add additional DU type `Unhandled` that has another kind of logic applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the details of the `actor` computation are, but if `Unhandled` is a value of the underlying computation type, you can certainly produce it using `return!`

Without knowing the details, I think something like this *should* work:

```
match msg with
| "stop" -> return 0
| "unhandled" -> return! Unhandled
| x -> 
    mailbox.Sender() <! x
    return! loop ()
```